# Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled. I'm getting this error while running in server

Tags: wcf, service

And this is my web.config file:

```
<services>
       <!--Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation.-->
      <service name="_1C_GBCService.GBCService" behaviorConfiguration="GBCServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="_1C_GBCService.IGBCService" />
         <!--Add the following endpoint.  
         Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint.--> 
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GBCServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!--policyVersion="Policy15"-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's mowst probably because you haven't defined any address for your endpoint as pointed below

```
    <endpoint address="" <-- Here
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          contract="_1C_GBCService.IGBCService" />
```

Define a address for your endpoint

```
 <service name="_1C_GBCService.GBCService" behaviorConfiguration="GBCServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="GBCService"
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          contract="_1C_GBCService.IGBCService" />
       <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        ......

   </service>
</services>
```

Then you can try discovering your service WSDL file using the URL `http://localhost:8080/`